# Azure Spatial Anchor Region Avalability

Tags: azure, augmented-reality, azure-spatial-anchors

I want to create a wayfinding app for a specific building using AR Core.
Because Google Cloud Anchor service has a 24-hour limit, I thought the Azure Spatial Anchor Service might do the job.
But my location is in East Europe. According to the docs, East Europe is not yet supported.

Has anyone tried these services from my location?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try using either West Europe or North Europe. They're the closest regions that we have Azure Spatial Anchors in to eastern Europe. (You can get a sense for the Azure network's RTT to various points on the global from the [Azure network round trip latency statistics page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/networking/azure-network-latency). It's between Azure data centers, so it doesn't take into account things like the app user's cell provider/ISP.)

Also, take a look at the [effective anchor experience guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/concepts/guidelines-effective-anchor-experiences) for some recommendation about building your UX. For example, consider designing the locating experience assuming the user will spend a few seconds doing that and may need to create a new anchor if an existing one cannot be found. Also, look for opportunities to create a watcher while something else is happening in your app so that you can overlap multiple operations that the user needs to wait for.

For example, in one of our apps, we start loading 3D assets and create a watcher at the same time. When the assets are done loading, we switch to an AR view, and, often, the anchor has also been located by the time the assets have loaded. If not, the UX can handle that case too.